# matrix exponential and Spectral abscissa

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Prove that

$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \|e^{tA}\| = 0$ if and only if $\alpha(A) < 0 $, where $\alpha$ is the Spectral abscissa, defined as $\max{Re(\lambda_i)}$.

I tried to approach this problem by proving that $\|e^{tA}\| \leq \|e^{t\alpha(A)}\|$ but didn't succeed. The hints given is First show what happens when you exponentiate a triangular matrix. But I still don't know how to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. You should use the Jordan decomposition $A=U^{-1}JU$, express the exponential as $\mathrm{e}^{tA}=U^{-1}\mathrm{e}^{tJ}U$, and realize the following two facts:

a. If all the real parts of the eigenvalues are negative, then indeed $\mathrm{e}^{tA}\to 0$.

b. If a real part of an eigenvalue is non-negative then $\mathrm{e}^{tA}\not\to 0$.

More specifically,
$A \,=\, U^{-1}JU,$
where
\begin{equation*}
J\,=\,\left(\begin{array}{llll} J_0 & & & 0 \\ & J_1 & &  \\ & &
\ddots &
\\ 0 & & & J_k \end{array}\right)\,=\,\mathrm{diag(}J_0,J_1,\ldots,J_k),
\end{equation*}
with $\,J_0=\mathrm{diag}\bigl(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_{N_0}\bigr) \!\in\!
\mathbb C^{N_0\times N_0}\,$ while for $\ell=1,\ldots,k$
\begin{equation*}
J_\ell\,=\,\left(\begin{array}{lllllll}
\lambda_\ell & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_\ell & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_\ell & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda_\ell
\end{array}\right)\,\in\,\mathbb C^{N_\ell\times N_\ell},
\end{equation*}
and $\,N_0+N_1+\cdots +N_k=N$. For the powers of $J$ we have
\begin{equation*}
J^m\,=\,\mathrm{diag}\left(J_0^m,J_1^m,\ldots,J_k^m\right),
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{tJ} &=\, \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!} J^m \,=\,
\text{diag} \bigg( \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^m}{m!}J_0^m,
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^m}{m!}J_1^m, \ldots,
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^m}{m!}J_k^m \bigg) \\ &=\,
\mathrm{diag} \big( \mathrm{e}^{tJ_0},\mathrm{e}^{tJ_1},\ldots,\mathrm{e}^{tJ_k} \big).
\end{align*}
For 
$\,\ell=1,\ldots,k$:
\begin{equation*}
J_\ell \,=\, \lambda_\ell{\mathcal I}+S,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation}
S\,=\,\left(\begin{array}{lllllll}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation*}
S^2\,=\,\left(\begin{array}{lllllll}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right),\ldots,\,
S^{N_\ell-1}\,=\,\left(\begin{array}{lllllll}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}\right)\!,
\end{equation*}
and
$$
S^m \,=\, 0, \quad \text{for all}\,\, \,\,m\ge N_\ell.
$$
Hence the Neumann series corresponding to the exponential of $S$
is finite:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{tS} & \,=\, \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}
S^k\,=\,\sum_{k=0}^{N_l-1} \frac{t^k}{k!}S^k \\ & \,=\,
{\mathcal I}+tS+\frac{t^{2}}{2!}S^2 +\cdots+
\frac{t^{N_l-1}}{(N_l-1)!} S^{N_l-1},
\end{align*}
and since $S$ and ${\mathcal I}$commute
we have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{tJ_\ell} & \,=\, \mathrm{e}^{t(\lambda_\ell{\mathcal I}+S)} \,=\,
\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t{\mathcal I}}
\mathrm{e}^{tS} \,=\,\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t}{\mathcal I}\mathrm{e}^{tS}  \,=\,
\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t}\mathrm{e}^{tS}  \\
& \,=\, \mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t} \biggl( {\mathcal I}+tS+\frac{t^2}{2!}
S^2 +\cdots+ \frac{t^{N_l-1}}{(N_l-1)!}S^{N_l-1} \biggr) \\ &
\,=\, \left.\left( \begin{array}{ccccc} \mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t}
& t\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_{\ell} t} & \frac{t^2}{2!}\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t}
& \cdots & \frac{t^{N_l-1}}{(N_l-1)!}\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t} \\
& \mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t} & t\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t} & \cdots &
\frac{t^{N_l-2}}{(N_l-2)!}\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t} \\
& & & \ddots & \\ 0 & & & & \mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell t} \\
\end{array} \right)\!.\right.
\end{align*}

From the above we conclude that if
$\,\mathrm{e}^{tA}=\bigl(b_{ij}(t)\bigr)_{i,j=1}^N$, then
\begin{equation*}
b_{ij}(t)\,=\,\sum_{\ell=1}^m
p_\ell^{ij}(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_\ell\,t},
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda_\ell\!\in\!\mathbb C\,$ eigenvalue of $A$ and
$p_\ell^{ij}(t)$ a polynomial of degree at most the difference between the algebraic 
and geometric multiplicity of  $\lambda_\ell$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to show (a) and (b)? I'm still not sure how to prove them. Why would we only care about real parts of the eigenvalues?

Comment: @user2649814: See update.